# Show row number column from result set in oracle sql view

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to add an extra column so if I get, let's say, 4 rows in the result this column will have values 1,2,3,4.

I've tried ROWNUM, but since this is a view it shows the actual row number in the whole view, and that's not what I want.

Here is a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (RID NUMBER, RVAL VARCHAR2(100 BYTE));
INSERT INTO TEST (RID, RVAL) VALUES (1, 'ONE');
INSERT INTO TEST (RID, RVAL) VALUES (2, 'TWO');
INSERT INTO TEST (RID, RVAL) VALUES (3, 'THREE');
INSERT INTO TEST (RID, RVAL) VALUES (4, 'FOUR');

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VTEST AS 
SELECT ROWNUM AS NUMROW, RID, RVAL FROM TEST;
```

Here are two sample queries. The first shows the result I want. The second how I want to get it (with a simple select against the view)

```
SELECT ROWNUM,RID,RVAL FROM TEST WHERE RID = 3 OR RID = 4;    
SELECT * FROM VTEST WHERE RID = 3 OR RID = 4;
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e816/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in oracle use **ROW_NUMBER** [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Comment: I've checked ROW_NUMBER but I don't know how to use it in this case. I need the field to form part of the view and update depending on the result set, if that's possible. I have extended the question to explain it better. Check out this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e816/3

Comment: Here is what I got using ROW_NUMBER. What am I doing wrong? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da55b7/2

Comment: @elcodedocle line number can not be calculated in the view, it will still be the same all the references to data and filter, you must calculate in the select

`SELECT row_number () over (order by rid) AS ROW_NUMBER, RID, Rval FROM TEST WHERE RID = 3 OR RID = 4;

SELECT row_number () over (order by RID) AS ROW_NUMBER, NUMROW, RID, Rval FROM  vTest WHERE RID = 3 OR RID = 4;
`

Comment: That's what I imagined. Thanks for the confirmation :-)